# Why is normal JSON structure returning undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get values from a nested JSON response using the normal JSON structure, but I am getting ´undefined´ returned in the console.

Anyone have an idea of why? :-)

**The jQuery:**

```
$.getJSON('https://www.example.net/stats/stats?brands=481,482,483&Date=06-30-2021%2000:00:001', function(data) {
  
  console.log(data.Data.TotalCases)

});
```

**The JSON response of `data`**

```
{
   "ContentEncoding":null,
   "ContentType":null,
   "Data":"{\"TotalCases\":13,\"CasesNewSince\":2,\"CasesDue\":13,\"CasesDueIn60\":0,\"CasesOverDue\":0,\"CasesDueInXminutes\":0,\"CasesDueIn1day\":13,\"CasesDueIn2day\":0,\"CasesDueIn3day\":0,\"CasesDueIn4day\":0,\"CasesDueIn5day\":0,\"CasesDueIn6day\":0,\"CasesDueIn7day\":0,\"CasesNewSincePercent\":0,\"CasesDuePercent\":100,\"CasesDueIn60Percent\":0,\"CasesOverDuePercent\":0,\"CasesDueInXminutesPercent\":0,\"CasesDueIn1dayPercent\":100,\"CasesDueIn2dayPercent\":0,\"CasesDueIn3dayPercent\":0,\"CasesDueIn4dayPercent\":0,\"CasesDueIn5dayPercent\":0,\"CasesDueIn6dayPercent\":0,\"CasesDueIn7dayPercent\":0}",
   "JsonRequestBehavior":0,
   "MaxJsonLength":null,
   "RecursionLimit":null
}
```

**The JSON response of `data.Data`**

```
{
   "TotalCases":14,
   "CasesNewSince":2,
   "CasesDue":14,
   "CasesDueIn60":0,
   "CasesOverDue":0,
   "CasesDueInXminutes":0,
   "CasesDueIn1day":14,
   "CasesDueIn2day":0,
   "CasesDueIn3day":0,
   "CasesDueIn4day":0,
   "CasesDueIn5day":0,
   "CasesDueIn6day":0,
   "CasesDueIn7day":0,
   "CasesNewSincePercent":0,
   "CasesDuePercent":100,
   "CasesDueIn60Percent":0,
   "CasesOverDuePercent":0,
   "CasesDueInXminutesPercent":0,
   "CasesDueIn1dayPercent":100,
   "CasesDueIn2dayPercent":0,
   "CasesDueIn3dayPercent":0,
   "CasesDueIn4dayPercent":0,
   "CasesDueIn5dayPercent":0,
   "CasesDueIn6dayPercent":0,
   "CasesDueIn7dayPercent":0
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like JSON - `data.Data` is a string. Trying to access the `TotalCases` property of a string results in undefined. What's generating the JSON?

Comment: It seems that `Data` got stringified first, then the whole object (including the stringified `Data`) got stringified again. This is something that should be fixed at the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `data.Data` is a string representation of JSON. You need to use [`JSON.parse(data.Data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and it should work.

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.example.net/stats/stats?brands=481,482,483&Date=06-30-2021%2000:00:001', function(response) {
  
  let data = JSON.parse(response.Data);
  
  console.log(data.TotalCases)

});
```

Comment: If you have any control over the API sending the data, you really should fix the problem at the source, not with this hack.

Comment: I agree, but if the OP is using  public API that might not be possible.

Comment: Brilliant @tftd! .. Yes, that fixed it, I now get the values out I need .. Thank you :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so others know this question is resolved. :)

Comment: @tftd I get delay on acceptance of answer .. will do as soon as the system allows me :-)